# Downloading a file (with expo) — Why is this so hard?

Tags: react-native, download

I've been trying multiple ways to download a file to local storage in react native, non of which are working. Here's my code in App.js where I am calling FileSystem.downloadAsync.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Image, Linking, PixelRatio, ListView } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import MainScreen from './Components/MainScreen'
import FileSystem from 'react-native-filesystem';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {     
    return (

      FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
        FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4'
      )
        .then(({ uri }) => {
          console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        }),

      <AppStackNavigator />
    );
  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main:{
    screen: MainScreen
  }
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Recap', () => App);
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

I'm very new to react native and javascript, but why does simply downloading a file seem to be so difficult, any help?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 25):

I haven't tested this on ios, but it works perfectly on Android, saving file to Download directory:

```
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

downloadFile(){
    const uri = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
    let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "small.mp4";
    FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
        this.saveFile(uri);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
}

saveFile = async (fileUri: string) => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status === "granted") {
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri)
        await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false)
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched many thread about saving to gallery with Expo, and I can confirm your steps working on both IOS and Android, thank you

Comment: @JyotirmayaPrusty your solution works well on Android, but it's returning this on IOS: Save error:  [Error: Asset couldn't be saved to photo library]. I'm in the process of finding a solution but my guess is that the problem is from this line:
const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri). There is something wrong with the method

Comment: Great answer. But what if it is an audio file or a pdf that I download. How do I move them to my storage.

Comment: This is not working in Iphone, can anyone help me on this

Comment: Which expo sdk you used for this example?

Comment: @KamalHossain, "sdkVersion": "35.0.0"

Comment: Doesn't this creates two files on your device? One from the downloadAsync() function (in the expo folder you can't access) and one from the createAssetAsync() ?

Comment: I use your code, but I receive this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this2.saveFile'). Can you plz help me?

Comment: @Unico delete 'this' from this.saveFile(uri);

Answer (score 10):

I tried too many solutions but this worked perfectly fine for me. No compatibility issues for **iOS**, **Android 10**, and **Android 11+**

**Imports**

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
const { StorageAccessFramework } = FileSystem;
```

**Initials**

```
const [downloadProgress, setDownloadProgress] = React.useState();
const downloadPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + (Platform.OS == 'android' ? '' : '');
```

**Ensure directory exists**

```
const ensureDirAsync = async (dir, intermediates = true) => {
    const props = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dir)
    if (props.exist && props.isDirectory) {
        return props;
    }
    let _ = await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(dir, { intermediates })
    return await ensureDirAsync(dir, intermediates)
}
```

**Show download progress**

```
const downloadCallback = downloadProgress => {
    const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    setDownloadProgress(progress);
};
```

**Download initiat for android/ios**

```
const downloadFile = async (fileUrl) => {
    if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
      const dir = ensureDirAsync(downloadPath);
    }

    let fileName = fileUrl.split('Reports/')[1];
    //alert(fileName)
    const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
      fileUrl,
      downloadPath + fileName,
      {},
      downloadCallback
    );

    try {
      const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
      if (Platform.OS == 'android')
        saveAndroidFile(uri, fileName)
      else
        saveIosFile(uri);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('download error:', e);
    }
}
```

**Save android file in public directory**

```
const saveAndroidFile = async (fileUri, fileName = 'File') => {
    try {
      const fileString = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
      
      const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
      if (!permissions.granted) {
        return;
      }

      try {
        await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, fileName, 'application/pdf')
          .then(async (uri) => {
            await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, fileString, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
            alert('Report Downloaded Successfully')
          })
          .catch((e) => {
          });
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
      }

    } catch (err) {
    }
  }
```

**Save ios file**

```
  const saveIosFile = (fileUri) => {
      // your ios code
      // i use expo share module to save ios file
  }
```

References: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

Comment: Very useful answer in tutorial format, thanks Irfan

Comment: Exactly! This is very helpful, saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download all types of files in expo sdk-38, it was not at all hard, There is just one problem,
You will have to create a folder (maybe with your app name if you like), then download all files in that(or their children), Images/video will show up directly, to see other files you will have to download related file-explorer.
see reference

```
downloadFile = async (url) =>{ 
    let path = url.split('/');
    const file_name = path[path.length-1];
     FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      url,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + file_name
    )
      .then(({ uri }) => {
        console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
        MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri).then(asset => {
          console.log('asset', asset);
        MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('myfolder', asset)
          .then(() => {
            showMessage({
              message: t('general.success'),
                description: t('download.success'),
              type: 'success'
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            showMessage({
              message: t('general.success'),
                description: t('download.failed'),
              type: 'danger'
            });
          });
        });
        
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Keep in mind Im downloading files (Xls, doc, etc) via HTTP URL, then converting it into local URI, if you already have local URI (maybe from expo-camera / expo-image-picker lib). You should use the above code from line 9
Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

replace your

```
import FileSystem from 'react-native-filesystem';
```

by

```
import { FileSystem } from 'expo';
```

Comment: You right but the file doesn't download to the device storage...
you get something like: 
Finished downloading to  file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540idanlevi1%252FStartachHapRev/hamburger.jpg

but where is it on the device? nowhere...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Download seems to work but cannot be found anywhere in the device filesystem.

Comment: Test it on a real device and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So by the looks of it, it seems the above functionality has not been developed yet as a feature of Expo as many people are requesting it -

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/ability-to-save-files-on-internal-storage

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution to this! It is not a great solution, and it is a total hack but I just tested it and it works great without needing any extra packages or permissions. it works with any file.

```
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native';
...
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll( fileURI, 'photo');
```

This moves the file into the root DCIM directory. Which means it is accessible via USB, or file explorer. It is a straight up hack and probably an oversight on someones part to not check mimetype, but its working!

Comment: No longer works.  `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Error decoding image data <NSData 0x...; 671 bytes>`

Answer (score 0):

I have used a mix of the current answers to get my solution that allows you to download a file then share it to the correct app types on your phone.

```
import { shareAsync } from "expo-sharing";
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';  


downloadFile = async (url) =>{ 
  let pathNoAtt = url.split("?")
  console.log(pathNoAtt)
  let pathWithCompany = pathNoAtt[0].split('/');
  let path = pathWithCompany[pathWithCompany.length-1];
  //firebase only
  let usingFirebase =true
  if(usingFirebase){
  const file_name = path.split("%2F")[path.split("%2F").length-1]
  }else{
  const file_name = path
  }
  console.log(file_name)

  FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    url,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory+ file_name
  )
    .then(async ({ uri }) => {
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
      MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri).then(asset => {
        console.log('asset', asset);
        this.share(asset)
      MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Downloads', asset)
        .then(() => {
             alert("download complete")
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("issue with download contact support")
        });
      });
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}


async share(asset){

  console.log(asset.filename.split("."))

  console.log(asset.filename.split(".").length)

  await shareAsync(asset.uri, { UTI: "."+asset.filename.split(".")[asset.filename.split(".").length-1], mimeType: "application/"+asset.filename.split(".")[asset.filename.split(".").length-1]});
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error: Could not create asset.`